# How to debug Office add-in activation issues?

Tags: ms-office

I have an Outlook add-in ("Apps for Office" type, i.e. HTML, not VSTO or COM) that is [published in the Office store](https://store.office.com/de-de/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380335).

Some users have complained that the add-in appears grayed out ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/mganss/EmojiAddIn/issues/3#)). I cannot reproduce the issue on my machine. The "Microsoft Office Alerts" event log on the user's machine shows only "Activated App" events.

How can I diagnose the problem (logging etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is usually a good tool for tracing the web requests. Otherwise there are general guidelines for troubleshooting loading issues here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting.

For issues loading your add-in, including run-time logging, see here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest

Also check the local cache for the manifest; see: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/troubleshoot-outlook-add-in-activation

Comment: The issue is not with functionality in the add-in but occurs before the add-in can be activated (i.e. clicked on in the Outlook toolbar). No error messages are displayed, the add-in simply appears grayed out (not clickable). I was hoping there was some sort of logging functionality in Outlook that allows you to track down the issue.

Comment: I've added another suggestion to my answer

Comment: Thanks, but this applies only to Outlook 2016. The problem occurs on Outlook 2013. Also, this seems to only log events related to the manifest.

Comment: But if your add-in isn't loading, then troubleshooting the manifest is the first thing to do. I found another article that I remembered having useful advice, especially regarding looking for the manifest in the local cache (answer updated)